How to put a IP static in Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to put a static IP in my Ubuntu 24.04, but I don't know how to do it. I have changed these files just like that.
50-cloud-init.yaml

00-installer-config.yaml:


does thisLinuxConfig article answer your queston?

The dhcp4 and dhcp6 parameters need to be set to false in the /etc/netplan file(s).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    en01:
      addresses:
        [192.168.0.4/26]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        search: [local]
        addresses:  [1.1.1.1, 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      dhcp6: false 
      dhcp4: false

Also, ensure that no other .yaml file in /etc/netplan directory overrides these settings. The following criteria provide that

all the other .yaml files that start with a lower number on their filenames have the same settings, which are dhcp[4,6]: false, or
those files have to be disabled, if possible, by renaming their extensions to different strings than exactly .yaml.

The .yaml files with names starting with a higher number do not override the settings in the file under consideration.

Rather than provide screenshots of directory listings or file configs, it's better practice at AskUbuntu to copy/paste the text into your answer as code blocks.
